# Getting a range of items from a large sorted list of tuples

Tags: python, list, search, tuples

I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
[(334.99972431901307, 0.0), (335.00088248902574, 0.0), (335.0020406650446, 0.0), (335.0031988470696, 66.83868408203125), (335.00435703510072, 252.91905212402344), (335.0055152291381, 341.447509765625), (335.00667342918183, 282.1964111328125), (335.0078316352317, 125.92335510253906), (335.00898996725408, 0.0), (335.01014818531672, 0.0)]
```

The list has a length of 16665 and is sorted on the first element of each tuple. I want to extract a certain range of tuples from the list based on that first tuple value. At the moment I do it like this:

```
def getSpectra_mzWindow(self, mzStart, mzEnd):
    for spectrum in self.mzmlInstance:
        # loop through all the peaks
        for peak in spectrum.peaks:
            # it's ordered, so when peak[0] > mzEnd it can stop
            if float(peak[0]) > mzEnd:
                break
            if mzStart <= float(peak[0]) <= mzEnd:
                yield spectrum, peak
```

However, this is incredibly slow. Since I know it's sorted on the first value, is there a faster way to do this than looping through the whole list? I was thinking of implementing a binary search, but is there already a library that has optimized on a list of sorted tuples?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module

Comment: Don't I then still need to loop through the list to put all the first values of the tuple in a list to get the index, to get back to the list of tuples to get the right tuple out?

Comment: @NiekdeKlein, you can probably search for a tuple like `(mzStart, 0.0)`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to adapt these examples to your purpose:  http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists.  Instead of retrieving the value in each function you can give the index back, and then use the two indices to extract your range.